# Traefik does not work with container deployed on worker node (swarm)

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik

I am running docker in swarm mode.

Server A is my manager
Server B is my worker

I have a lot of containers running on A, and just start B to help with some of the workload.

The problem is that if a container is deployed on A, Traefik will route requests to it, but if container ends up on B it will give me bad gateway.

My `traefik` stack:

```
version: '3.6'

networks:
  traefik-net:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
    external: true
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --docker --docker.swarmmode --docker.domain=mydomain.com --docker.watch --api  # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen 
      - /home/walucas/docker-configs/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /home/walucas/docker-configs/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    deploy:
      labels:
        traefik.port: 8080
        traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:traefik.mydomain.com"
        traefik.docker.network: traefik-net
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
```

My `whoami` stack:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  whoami:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    ports:
      - "8089:8000"
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:whoami.mydomain.com"
        traefik.port: "8000"
        traefik.docker.network: traefik-net
networks:
  traefik-net:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
    external: true
```

I am not sure if thats a network issue or a traefik issue.

(note) Server B is on another physical location than server A.

Comment: Have you opened the overlay networking ports between the hosts? (See the prerequisites https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) Can you connect between any two containers on different nodes and on the same overlay network?

Comment: I am using an overlay. After reading the doc, I opened the doors that were required, but I am suspecting that the issue is on server B hosting firewall rules (which I dont have access)